# Interest from Saving Account and Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes

Last year, I made less than $10 in interest; as such, I didn't receive 1099 forms. This year, however, I made quite a sizable amount of interest, namely $84.00. I just had my taxes done and this information, of course, was reported. My question is whether or not such a change in savings account interest (from $0 - $84) would trigger an audit.

Comment: Note also that my AGI was $25,000.

Comment: If they looked into such trivial (de minimus) matters, they probably wouldn't flag it for an audit if you reported $84,000 in interest income. That's not what they focus on.  On the other hand, if you have gross income in the tens of millions of dollars, and are reducing your income for large write-offs, such that you pay very little tax, then you are probably going to trigger one of their audit flags.

Answer (score 3):

While there's no "official" audit triggers, some things are known to have triggered audits. Having savings is not one of them, so if you do get audited - it would likely to be a random thing, not something triggered by your reported interest.

That said, the fact that last year you had less than $10 in interest means you didn't get 1099, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't have reported and pay taxes on it.